# Neurological supercharger out of thin air

Tags: science-based, creature-design, evolution, xenobiology, brain

Some speculation on a neurological [supercharger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercharger) for a sapient *alien* species:

- The supercharger is a natural biochemical compound of some sort produced and stored in a specialized brain-adjacent organ. Perhaps it's the byproduct of a symbiotic organism, perhaps something else.
- A critical part of the process depends on filtered and pressurized oxygen (or an equivalent reactive atmospheric gas) to fuel the reaction in the brain. This is also stored in the aforementioned organ.
- When in sufficient volume an individual can, at will, release the supercharger and gas mix directly to its brain (the bloodstream feeding it or a specialized circulatory system therein).
- The individual immediately experiences a rush and is capable of intense focus, leaps of intuition and creativity, precise movement, savantism – everything you'd expect of something that boosts brain activity well above typical levels. It doesn't last very long and begins to taper off shortly after; once the effect wears off the individual is exhausted and can't repeat it for quite a while. Overheating the brain is a real danger.

Where does this fall apart and how can it be salvaged?

Comment: I have got something much like this based on filtered and French pressurized coffee beans.

Comment: The only part where this falls apart is your terms: oxygen would not be a "fuel", it is the oxidizer that make the actual fuel — you call it "supercharger" — oxidize, and with that release its potential.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking for self-produced amphetamine.

It is possible and even "normal" (if in a lesser degree) it's called "adrenaline".

You "just" need your "aliens" to produce, with similar mechanisms, a hormone a bit more efficient (and, possibly, more brain-centered, as adrenaline acts also on other systems, including muscles).

Comment: So why would this xeno-adrenaline evolve to need a blast of pressurized *oxygen to work?

Comment: @rek: Psychotropic drugs (natural as adrenaline or artificial as many amphetamines) have *no* use of "pressurized Oxygen" (which, if released anywhere in the blood stream, would produce dangerous embolism), but could benefit from a higher oxygen content in the blood and muscles. This could be done via higher hemoglobin content or using some more efficient substitute for it. If you want to keep that mechanism you may want to speculate about an "inner lung" feed by pressurized oxygen reserve (perhaps evolved to cope with ancient marine dwelling) which can be used to help oxygenating under stress

Answer (score 2):

### It would work (within reasonable limits)

**There is always side-effects to tampering with brain-chemistry.**
If it was the best for the brain to simply work faster then why would it not have evolved that way?
Of course you burn a lot more calories, but there is other stuff, too.
Hormones might be released and you get into emotional distress or you could have long-term effects like depression or dependency.

**Differing results**

Let's take current day drugs that work with brain-chemistry in different ways.
Marijuana as an example. It does different things with every person.
Of course the main tendency is to calm them down and make them hungry, but for some rare people the same strain causes panic attacks, paranoia or even psychotic episodes.
(note: marijuana is a rather weak drug and is comparably not that dangerous)

**Body chemistry imbalance**

Also the side effects do not even have to be psychological or neurological issues, but can make your body chemistry go nuts and cause an imbalance in other organs causing them to malfunction when effected to severely.

**Physical limitations**

Then there is also the hard limits of the body. In the human body a signal travels about 128 m/s. So even if you were to enhance the speed in which neurons fire you wouldn't greatly increase that speed.
If a signal is supposed to travel 20cm in your brain it would at least take 1.5ms to reach the destination.
You can not enhance the 'computational power' indefinitely.

**Conclusion**

There are already methods to enhance focus, but they all have side-effects to some extend.
None of the methods can boost indefintely.
You could argue that an aliens physiology might be better "boostable" and with futuristic technology it can work to much stronger extends, but even then it will have its limitations.
There is no inherent issue with "boosting" biochemistry. Just side-effects and limitations.

Comment: I just wanted to add the obvious, you are talking about the possibilities of alien biology, the possibilities are almost endless.

Comment: @anon if the question was meant that way i doubt it would have been asked. If "alien technology makes anything possible" was an answer he was looking for he wouldn't have bothered asking. He wanted to know reasonable criticism on the idea of supercharging a biological organism.

Comment: @ArtificialSoul If the biology is alien it is kind of by definition unknowable to us.

Comment: Im not saying your answer is wrong, it has very good points. I'm just saying there's a fairly obvious fact that should be mentioned in that its "Alien Biology" the possibilities are endless. Heck alien biology could be such that absolutely all of your points are irrelevant.

Comment: @anon Well, even then it would have limitations. Processing anything takes time, chemical reactions take time. Even if you enhance the speed at which the biochemistry works without side effects physics still puts a limit on the maximum enhancement possible.

Comment: Yes and no, even in our own physiology there are varying degrees of processing times much of which is governed by our biology but if you have a more adaptive biology those constraints become ambiguous. Of course you are limited by physics but that's fairly out of scope. For instance our natural perception of time is roughly 30FPS, in an adrenal state is can be higher than 60 FPS has nothing to do with physics but is simply a product of our evolution.

Comment: @anon yes, that is exactly what i said. You can boost biochemistry, but with side-effects. Adrenalin has lots of them. All my answer was concluding to is that there is no inherent issue with boosting biochemistry, but there are limitations and possible side-effects. No matter what the actual scope is within alien biology.

Comment: And I wasnt disagreeing with you, but it still should be mentioned that those "side effects" are a product of our own biology. Its entirely plausible an alien octopus can eat an alien fish and become sentient for 5hrs then regress to its natural state with no side effects.

Comment: @anon I have to disagree for two reasons. 1. becoming sentient is change brain functionality NOT brain focus. You don't learn random new stuff by taking drugs. your experiences and thought processes change. 2. it is reasonable to assume this alien biology evolved naturally. And assuming a naturally evolved system can just be pumped up with suff and then work incredibly more efficient with no side-effects is ludicrous.

Comment: @ArtificialSoul that is based on your bias stemming from human physiology. Apparent Behavior is purely the result of biology and sentience is an apparent behavior. An organism could have all the physical structure needed for sentience but behaviorally not utilize it unless under certain circumstances, like the presence of a protein.

Comment: @anon that bias comes from evolutionary biology/psychology. Every system requires energy. Sentience is currently seen as a function of the brain, as said by Robert Kurzban. Why would a system develop that would never be used? Why waste energy and resources on building and sustaining that? Wouldn't not having that system be an evolutionary advantage? Why would that not prevail over the less energy-efficient version?

Comment: @ArtificialSoul Your question about why it would evolve this way (external to the brain and temporary, rather than innate and more moderate but permanent) is the sort of "where it falls apart" I was hoping to see addressed.

Comment: @rek my answer it is addressing that. It does not fall apart. You have not given enough details to disprove the spefics of your supercharger. So all any answer can is argue whether or not the basic concept works and what it's limitations are.

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot increase neuron transmission speed according to artificial soul, you should seek to increase amount of active grey matter in the brain. That means doing parallel computing with more neurons. It is like few computers working together, and each tackles a part of the solution's algorithm. This increase also needs extra oxygen and sugars.

Comment: The *how* of it really isn't central to the question I've asked: *why* it works this way rather than some other more likely alternative, is.

Comment: It may still give you the desired effect: Intense focus if more parts of the brain work together simultaneously (Opposite to focusing on a single event), would still need more oxygen for more cells, and sharpen reflexes like Adrenalin does. The brain controls this process, yet your mechanism just provides the fuel for it. Where it falls apart: Intelligence hinges on what problems you CAN solve, not just how quickly. If a concept is beyond the person's understanding, be it because of intelligence or learning experience, then most likely this Adrenalin rush will be in vain.